# Pure inductor as load in inverter

Tags: circuit-analysis, power-electronics, inverter, passive-networks

In the following inverter a pure inductive load is applied, then from where the starting current will start? (from 0 or -I(peak)). I want to draw the waveform of current through the inductor and find its peak value.

[image]

f = 50 Hz and inverter mode is 180.

Comment: If you don't already, it's worth getting to know how to use a simulator, then you can model things like these, see what they do and get a feel for them. Inductors are a bit trickier than resistors or capacitors to get your head around. LTSpice is good, and free, and is the *de facto* standard for hobbyists (and many engineers at work).

Comment: V=LdI/dt on a branch opening, yet I=200V/2Rsw, is huge if 2 switches across Vin are ON, thus the dead-time and diode current  from the impulse is a critical detail in future after you sort out the sequence to create the dead-time.

Comment: @Neil_UK I'm using Linux and I don't think LTSpice supports linux!

Comment: NGSpice supports Linux.

Comment: I'm using Linux, Mint 18 Mate to be specific, and both LTSpice IV and XVII install fine under Wine. A caution though. If you install Wine through apt-get install using the standard repos, you don't get the latest version, and only LTSpice IV works with it. If you google around, you can find out how to get Wine 1.8 by adding a ppa, that will run both versions of LTSpice.

Comment: try this http://tinyurl.com/gpxnxxn

Comment: @AnshKumar with due respect to Tony, who is an EE since 1975 (one year longer than me), while that simulator will make pretty pictures, it's well worth the effort to get up the learning curve on a 'real' simulator, that will repay dividends over your lifetime if you choose to continue with electronics as a hobby, career or both.

Comment: This is a pure inductor used in the circuit(theoretically), so there shouldn't be any transient behavior involved.

Comment: Who says 'should'? You, or nature? Even with a theoretically pure inductor, behaviour consists of an initial transient, which dies away, and long term behaviour which is (well) long term. If you try to tell nature how to behave, you end up confused, because it doesn't hear or obey you. If you are modest, see what nature does, and try to understand that, then you will make progress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behaviour of an inductor takes most people by surprise initially.

In answer to comments here, and your other question, let's see what the current in an inductor does when fed with a sinewave voltage source, everything starting at 0. This is produced in LTSpice XVII, running under Wine 1.8, under Linux Mint 18

[image]

The inductor current (blue, right scale) starts from 0, builds, falls again to 0, builds again. It stays positive valued only, at least over this time scale with these conditions, in an offset cosine fashion. The conditions are, the inductor series resistance is very small, only 1mohm. As the inductor inductance is 1mH, that gives a time constant of 1 second, L/R. As we are looking out only to 10mS, very little changes in that time.

Now let's have a look with a larger value of series resistance. I change the R to 100mohm. This gives an L/R time constant of 10mS.

[image]

What's happened? Now we can see the transient behaviour starting to die out, the blue current trace is moving down to become centred around 0. After one time constant, it's got a bit more than halfway to where it's going.

Let's try looking out even further, and use an L/R of 1mS.

[image]

Now by the end of the 10mS trace, 10 time constants, the current trace has completely settled down to being bipolar around 0. In fact, if you look back, it's not visually distinguishable from that after 5 time constants

If R was zero, then the initial transient would continue indefinitely, as the L/R time constant is infinite. That's where the continuous current in superconductors comes from, it's a transient that doesn't die away.

**Compared with Capacitors**

If you want to understand inductors by comparison with capacitors, then it can be done, but you need to take the **dual** circuit. That means switching series for shunt, and current for voltage.

Consider a sinewave *current source* starting at 0, feeding a capacitor with initial zero voltage. The voltage will build from 0, peak, fall back to 0 again in an offset cosine fashion. You can use the traces above to illustrate what happens, green trace as the current source, and blue trace as the voltage. For the simple capacitor case, the traces are as in the first, transient only, plot.

Now if you add a shunt resistor across the capacitor, the offset voltage will fall, bleed off through the resistor, and eventually its voltage will be swinging equally about zero, as in the third plot.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on which switches fire first.  If top-left and bottom-right close first, \$ i_o \$ will be positive first.  Otherwise, negative.

Either way, the current will start at zero.

Comment: ... and the current will start from zero

Comment: Good call!  Forgot to mention that.

Comment: If the current starts from 0, in a time period the current will end to 0, making the inverter operation useless because we will be getting dc current and I(peak) = 20 which is wrong. I(peak) = 10.

Comment: @AnshKumar see my answer here: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/281398/how-does-a-negative-current-start-in-the-inductor-in-ac-circuit